# Load text file into single string and table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to do the following:

- Load a text file into a single string
- Remove all characters from the string that are not letters
- Then break the string into a table that each row has 5 characters

```
def dataFile:
    dataFile = open("data.txt", "r")
    for character in dataFile:
        lines = character.readlines()
    dataFile.close()
    return
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the code you wrote to satisfy that wish that we could help you with?

Comment: I am new to python, what im trying to do here here is create a cipher that will find a secret word in a paragraph of a text

Comment: `for character in dataFile` is misleading. When iterating over a file, the result of each iteration is a *full line* of text. I.e.  `for line in dataFile` is more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can use the `isalpha()` method.

You should do it as follows:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as your_file:
    lines = your_file.readlines()

lines = ''.join(line.strip() for line in lines)
lines = ''.join(letter for letter in lines if letter.isalpha())

char_per_line = 5

result = [lines[i:i+char_per_line] for i in range(0, len(lines), char_per_line)]
```

[EDITED]

```
key = [5,6,3,7,4,6,3,5,3]

for index,line in zip(key, result):
    print line[index]
```

[EDITED AGAIN]

```
for index,line in zip(key, result):
    print line[:index]+line[index].upper()+line[index+1:]
```

Comment: I am very grateful @sshashank124 this worked according to what I'm trying to accomplish. Now what if I have a key like key = [5,6,5,4,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,5,6] this should be able to reveal the hidden message

Comment: I have accepted your answer but If you don't mind would be in a position to help with the above question in the comment?

Comment: @bisera, I'm sorry I didn't understand that last commment. Can you please reword? Thank you

Comment: @sshashank123: basically I want to use a key to find the hidden word for example if i have key =[5,6,5,4,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,5,6] it should print the hidden word like thiis A rray

Comment: @bisera, so you mean the 5th char of the first line, 6th char of the second line, 5th char of the third line and so on....?

Comment: @sshashank123: Yes! that is exactly it

Comment: @bisera, I will updated my answer. Please wait for a few minutes.

Comment: @bisera, Note: I have updated my answer. Certain things, your key list has values of 6 and 5 but remember that you asked for only 5 per line so the index only goes from 0-4. Either you can increase char_per_line or change your list of index. Hope that helps.

Comment: @sshashank123: Thanks it worked as expected but now for some finishing touches I want to print the whole characters. for example thisis A is, iwas R getting. The capital letters represent the hidden message

Comment: line[index] is out of range

Comment: @bisera, As I mentioned, Note: I have updated my answer. Certain things, your key list has values of 6 and 5 but remember that you asked for only 5 per line so the index only goes from 0-4. Either you can increase char_per_line or change your list of index. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

1. load a text file into a single string:

   ```
   with open('data.txt') as file: 
       text = file.read()
   ```
2. remove all characters from the string that are not letters:

   ```
   letters = filter(str.isalpha, text)
   ```
3. then break the string into a table that each row has 5 characters:

   ```
   from itertools import zip_longest

   result = list(map(''.join, zip_longest(*[iter(letters)]*5, fillvalue='')))
   ```